# Grabbing :after content

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a css file that does something like this `#foo:after{content:"bar;}` , is there any way to get the contents of the :after with javascript? Getting the contents of the parent element just returns the content of the #foo element, not the :after bit.

Comment: you looking for a pure javascript solution or you can use jquery?

Comment: Pure javascript. jQuery isn't an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo elements can't be grabbed nor manipulated in JS because they don't actually exist in the DOM.

Comment: Then is there a way to insert CSS with content: when you aren't in a before or after context?